# importing and using a local package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-packaging

I created a local package.

```
python setup.py sdist #this created logger.tar.gz
```

then I create a venv, moved this file to venv, and installed it using the below command.

```
pip install logger.tar.gz
```

when I tried to import and use it, the functionality is not working.
attaching my code below
**init**.py

```
#is empty
```

logger.py

```
import logging
import os
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

def loggerInterface(module,flag=None):

    <main logic>
        
    return logger
```

i want to use this package as

```
from logger import loggerInterface
#use loggerInterface here
```